Next.js Anti-CSRF Tokens Check on Google Cloud Run
I am hosting my Next.js application on Google Cloud Run. The code is stored in Github, and whenever i push some changes to main I have a Github action that checks the Next.js application for vulnerabilities.
.github/workflows/sec-node.yml
name: Security for Next.js - DAST for web with OASP ZAP

on: [push]

jobs:
  dast_scan:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: DAST (Dynamic Application Security Testing) with OASP ZAP
    steps:
      - name: ZAP Scan
        uses: zaproxy/action-full-scan@v0.10.0
        with:
          target: 'https://myapp-g6qfqggcha-lz.a.run.app'

ZAP Scan gives me the following issue:
Anti-CSRF Tokens Check [20012] total: 2:

https://myapp-g6qfqggcha-lz.a.run.app/signin
https://myapp-g6qfqggcha-lz.a.run.app/signup

So I understand that I have to add CSP policies, for example:
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https://trusted.cdn.com;
How is this done in Google Cloud Run? Or should it be done in the Next.js application code? Something like this to be included into every next.js page?
const cspHeader = "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://trusted-scripts.example.com; style-src 'self' https://trusted-styles.example.com; img-src 'self' https://trusted-images.example.com;";
I have a file named next.config.mjs. Can it be added in this file?
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: "standalone",
    images: {
        domains: ["avatars.githubusercontent.com", "cloudflare-ipfs.com", "dhzu9iazkoiza1a2.public.blob.vercel-storage.com", "unsplash.com"]
    }
};

export default nextConfig;

